# Can the simple 301 redirect plugin for WordPress cause a redirect Loop when trying to redirect to the same path, but on HTTPS?

Tags: seo, wordpress, 301-redirect, https, migration

I want to redirect `http://example.com/folder1/page1/` to `https://example.com/folder1/page1/`.
In simple 301 redirect plugin in the request part I should write: `/folder1/page1/`.

In the destination I may write `/folder1/page1/`.
Here is the problem. Wouldn't it cause redirect loop since both of the URLs are the same for the plugin?

Also for the homepage redirect should I write `/`?

Answer (score 1):

> Wouldn't it cause redirect loop since both of the URLs are the same for the plugin?

Yes. If you want to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS then you need to specifically check the protocol by which the site has been accessed. This is not part of the URL path.

> Also for the homepage redirect should I write /?

Yes.

Comment: The basic concept of redirect plugin is to take care for 404 pages, or if pages are moved from one directory to another. You can then specify a 301 redirect. Ideally, if you wanna change the http protocol, then it is better to provide the redirect at your cPanel hosting. The plugin won't be suitable for doing this. For more details, you can reach out to your hosting provider about how to configure http:// to https:// redirect.